# How to send value through URL in FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, send, dataprovider

I want to send current date with URL in flex from client side and want to get it on the server. I am using MXML and ActonScript.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/10/29/passing-parameters-to-an-httpservice/)'s an example of how to pass an object using the `HTTPService`'s `send()` method. Just wrap your `Date` object and pass it via a `send()` call.

Answer (score 0):

you may have a look at

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part4_data_access_1.html

and read from there to see, what you need for your kinf od request (HTML, XML).

in short, you have to have some dataservice (f.e. mx:HTTPService) and appropriate methods (send) and connect them with your controls

EDIT:
system time:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=08_Dates_and_times_3.html